# Load Google Analytics js file with CSP nonce

Tags: google-analytics, content-security-policy

I'm using the CSP `nonce` rule to load all my external JS scripts, that is, I don't trigger the `'unsafe-inline'`. Therefore it's safer.

Strangely with Google Analytics file, the browser is blocking the loading of files, loaded by the `analytics.js` script *per se*.

[image]

Anyone has experience of loading Google Analytics with CSP *and without* `'unsafe-inline'`, using [nonces or hashes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src)?

Comment: Do you get more debug if you click on that `collect` line and look at the `Headers/Preview` tab?

Comment: @Max I don't get any further relevant information. And I'm loading the `analytics.js` also with the `nonce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that [script-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) only works for your inline GA script, however subsequent `/collect` requests made by GA are `image/gif` requests. Try to use [img-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src) to allow those `/collect` calls:

```
Content-Security-Policy: img-src http://www.google-analytics.com
Content-Security-Policy: img-src https://www.google-analytics.com
```

Pick whichever match your protocol.